# How to design a database with python where you can have nodes with multiple parents?

Tags: python, database, database-design

So Im thinking about this way of organising information for a shop where you are able to find products in different categories, for example a Mousepad both in the gaming section and in the office section.

I was looking for databases with this functionality on the internet. I found django-treebeard, which gives the opportunity to create hierarchical graphs, but not with multiple parents for a node.

Then i found the library networkx, where it is possible to create socalled directed graphs, which have the entity of having multiple parents. The problem with that is only, that its not optimally fitted for the purpose of creating a database with pure information. Its made for data analysis, so that when you use it, you put each node in a koordinate-system with values signed to each node, in order to find the shorted path etc.

So i only need a system where it's possible to create a database with multiple parents for each node. I am thinking if there is a way to create some classes from scratch, but Im not experienced enough to be able to do that.

Can somebody help me? Maybe you know a library that suites my needs or you have created similar classes for a project which I could use? Or you know how for example Amazon handles this idea?

Many thanks in advance.

for example could we use this simple dataset:

```
parent_nodes = ["office", "gaming"]
child_nodes = ["Mousepad"]
edges = [("office", "Mousepad"), ("gaming", "Mousepad")]
```

where edges mean the connection between nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, summarizing you need a way of having categories for certain products. I would not use the terminology 'parent' and 'child', but 'item' and 'category'.

In a relational database this is a **many-to-many** relationship, and you could implement it as follows:

- Table 'category': it would have an autogenerated and unique ID, and a 'code', which would be 'office' and 'gaming' in your example.
- Table 'product': it would have an autogenerated and unique ID, and a 'name', which would be 'mousepad' in your example.
- Table 'product_category': it would store the relations bewteen the ID of both a 'category' and a 'product'.

It would be something like this:

**CATEGORY TABLE**

```
id  | code          |
----+---------------+
1   | office        |
2   | gaming        |
```

**PRODUCT TABLE**

```
id  | name          |
----+---------------+
1   | mousepad      |
```

**PRODUCT_CATEGORY TABLE**

```
category_id  | product_id  |
-------------+-------------+
1            | 1           |
2            | 1           |
```

In order to keep relations like this, if your Database is simple and not too big, I would recommend you to implement this approach by using [**SQLite**](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) or similar.